# Why applying isset to a multidimensional array increased execution time by 4000%?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array, isset

**EDIT:** It turns out that `$article->getID();` is the part responsible for the overscaled execution time. Here's what it looks like :

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

But still I have no idea why this is happening.

---

I'm using this code to try to compute `document frequency` for each token in a small corpus of 1000 documents and 4000 *unique* tokens.

To do so, I wrote this function :

```
public function computeIDF(){
    // splitting documents into tokens
    $this->tokens = $this->tokenize();
    // $this->tokens = array($article->id => array($token => $freq))

    // 1. For each token …
    foreach($this->tokens as $token){

        // 2. … look in every document …
        foreach($this->articles as $article){

            // 3. … and if it exists there …
            if(isset($this->tokens[$article->getID()][$token]){

                // 4. … add 1
                $tokFreq[$token] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But step 3. is causing a lot of trouble :
- if I comment out step `4.`, nothing changes;
- if I comment out step `3.`, execution time goes from `414.2s` to "just" `14s`, which is almost 4000% faster !!1! (So, definitely, this is NOT a "micro-optimization" issue.

**NOTE** No database is involved here. Everything was fetched way earlier, out of this entire `class`' scope :

```
// This is where the data is being fetched
$articles = ArticleDAO::loadLast(1000);

// It's then injected into the $corpus
$corpus = new Corpus($articles);
```

Am I doing something wrong here? If so, how can I make things faster?

Comment: What is that getter `$article->getID()` doing exactly? Just returning a property? Loading things from a database?

Comment: No database is involved here. Everything was fetched way earlier.

Comment: Mr. Downvoter, if you read this, do you mind explain your intentions? Thanks.

Comment: What happens with the execution time if you replace 3 with just `$article->getID();`?

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here! I ran the tests with `$article->getID();` and execution time skyrocketed again. Here's what it looks like from the inside : `public function getID(){ return $this->id; }` Any explanations, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to `$article->getID()` has overhead.  It has to save the stack, call the function, copy the result, then resume.  Because you're iterating each token for each article (instead of the other way around), each call to `getID` is going to be for a different article, so no shortcuts can be taken.

There's two things you can do:

1. Replace `$article->getID()` with just `$article->id`
2. Make your outer loop across articles and your inner loop across tokens.  This way you stay within an article for an entire batch of tokens which should help with caching.

Comment: Apparently, this is the cause for the latency I'm witnessing. Reversing the loops order is impossible (from a logic PoV), so I `public`'d the `$id` field in the `Article` class, at least, as a momentary workaround.

Comment: Why would reversing the loops be impossible?  It should net you the same results.  You still cover every combination of token/article.

Comment: Because my logic is broken, that's why. In the other hand, swapping loops would necessitate another loop, which may (or may not) add its load to the sauce. I'll be implementing this right away and we'll see what would happen. Thanks : )